# How to multiply with a constant a selected region of a gridded Netcdf file for all the variables with NCO or CDO?

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have a gridded netcdf file with several variables.

I want to multiply **all the variables** with a constant value c but ONLY for a selected region of the grid.

with NCO for one variable for example I do the following

```
ncap2 -s 'where((lat >= 40.55 && lat <= 40.7) && (lon >= 22.8 && lon <= 23)) var1=var1*0.55;' in.nc out.nc
```

since I have over 20 variables in the netcdf file , how I could define to multiply all the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ncap2`'s  Vpointer [functionality](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#vpointer)? Create a Vpointer list based on the variables you want. Loop through the list and apply the `where` statement you have above to each variable.